# Querying Kibana for the Latest Data

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, virtual-machine, kibana

I have an ELK (ElasticSearch, Logstash, & Kibana) stack running on an Azure VM (VM is running Windows Server 2012). Data points are successfully coming in, and I can obviously query those.

I'm having issues with more advanced queries. I've read the documentation on ElasticSearch's [site](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) extensively, and googled around but I can't seem to find anything regarding my issues. I would like to be able to query Kibana for the latest data points for a couple of things. For example, for each GUID (unit ID), three data points are logged (one for temp, one for vibration, etc.) and I would like to be able to query for the latest point of each of these.

I can query by name and timestamp, but I have not see any documentation or information regarding how to pull only the latest data point. I was thinking it may work to query for a range of data points (making the range small enough that only the newest point would be between the bounds), but that sounds rather inefficient, and if there's a way to do it better I would prefer to go that route.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/678) and [another](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3286).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for posting those.Nice to know it's not just me.